# Data Not Being Inserted Into Databse

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was actually making a login and registration system.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
    <h3>Register</h3>
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname"><br><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="btn">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
  <?php

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("fulllogin");

    if(isset($_POST['btn'])) {
        $name = $_POST['uname'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$name','$password')";
        mysql_query($query);
        echo "Successfully Inserted";
    }
    else {
        echo "Try Again";
    }
    ?>
```

Now the problem is that when I execute the code, the form works and there are no errors but there is the "try Again" message by default. And when I submit the form, nothing happens.

**PS**
The Name of the DB is fulllogin (with a triple l)

Comment: `<form action="#" method="POST">`

Comment: Do some google search and make your code proper. Use `mysqli` OR `PDO` for preventing SQL Injection.

Comment: Thanks. It works like a charm now.

Comment: `<form action="#" method="post">` you need to define the way your form are sended (and net time dont ask for a quick solution we dont get mony from you ;-))

Comment: Do not use the mysql functions, use either mysqli or PDO. mysql functions are depreciated, and have been removed from the current version of PHP. Also use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: It works now thanks to Saad Suri

Comment: **This code has two serious security problems**: SQL injection and plaintext passwords.

Comment: Yet another hacker's dream. Please read above comment 5 times and fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You didn't specify your form action. It should be `<form action="#" method="POST">`
2. Your INSERT query is wrong. You have to specify which column from `users` table you are inserting your new values to.

Change

> INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$name','$password')

to

> INSERT INTO users (column1, column2, column3)
>   VALUES('','$name','$password')

I would suggest for you to use `die(mysql_error())` to see the error on MySQL side and properly debug it. Also, take the commentor's advice to make your code more secure.